# Simple JavaScript Timer Function

Tags: javascript, timer

So, I've written a timer to start when the page loads, and to stop when the user clicks a "finished" button

```
    <br><button id = "finish" onclick = "stopTimer();">Done</button>
```

My code works fine, I was just wondering if there's a simpler/easier/faster way to implement a timer in Javascript?

```
//Stop timer function
function stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(time);
}

//Start timer function
var secTime = 0,
      minTime = 0,
      hourTime = 0;

var time =  setInterval(function(){
    var maxSec = 59,
        maxMin = 59,
        maxHour = 59;
if(secTime > maxSec){
      minTime++;
      if(minTime > maxMin){
        hourTime++;
        if(hourTime > maxHour){
          hourTime = 0;
          minTime = 0;
          secTime = 0;
        }
        minTime = 0
      }
      secTime = 0;
    }    
        var newSec = (secTime.toString().length == 1) ? '0' + secTime : secTime,
            newMin = (minTime.toString().length == 1) ? '0' + minTime : minTime,
            newHour = (hourTime.toString().length == 1) ? '0' + hourTime : hourTime;

        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = newHour + ':' + newMin + ':' + newSec;

    secTime++;    
}, 1000);
```

Comment: this might be better asked at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could do this in one line. Just subtract milliseconds, and convert into hours/minutes/seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can't count the time using `setInterval` because is not precise, but you can use the `setInterval` to calculate the difference (in seconds) of the datetime start and datetime stop and update the timer div on the page.

JS:

```
var dateTimeStart = new Date();
var intervalId;
var seconds = 0;

function start(){
    updateTimer();
    intervalId = setInterval(function(){
      seconds = Math.floor((new Date() - dateTimeStart) / 1000);
        updateTimer();
    }, 1000);
}

function stop(){
    clearInterval(intervalId);
}

function updateTimer(){
    var date = new Date(1970, 0, 1);
    date.setSeconds(seconds);
    document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = format(date);
}

function format(date){
  return twodigits(date.getHours()) + ':' + twodigits(date.getMinutes()) + ':' + twodigits(date.getSeconds());
}

function twodigits(number){
    var str = '0' + number;
    return str.substr(-2);
}

function action(name){
    document.getElementById('action').innerHTML = name;
}

start();
```

HTML:

```
<div id="timer"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="stop();">STOP</button>
```

**[Check the demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koa2w936/2/)**